# Typescript and equivalent js code

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am starting with typescript and I came across John Papa's tutorial. He had the following:

```
// TypeScript
class Car {  
    // Property (public by default)
    engine: string;

    // Constructor 
    // (accepts a value so you can initialize engine)
    constructor(engine: string) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

**the equivalent js code:**

```
// JavaScript
var Car = (function () {  
    function Car(engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    return Car;
})();
```

It got me confused. Shouldn't it be:

```
    function Car(engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The JavaScript effectively is exactly what you suggest. Note that the value of `Car` will be the *return value* from that anonymous function, and that anonymous function is executed as part of the `var` initialization. Thus `Car` ends up being exactly that small function you think it should be.

Comment: Are you asking why it's being wrapped in a function execution and assigned to a variable instead of just having the function?

Comment: Now, why is it that way? It's code produced by a transpiler. In the general case of translating TypeScript `class` declarations, that structure makes sense.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarification. I guess I looked into the equivalent code and did not even think for a moment that it might be just from the transpiler.

Comment: Also, when targeting `es6` the compiler will keep the class syntax as it is supported in es6 javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right but there is a reason for the TypeScript code to look like that...

It becomes more obvious once you add some methods to your class:

```
class Car {  
    engine: Engine;
    constructor(engine: Engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    drive() { 
        this.engine.start();
    }
}
```

The output JS look as follows:

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    Car.prototype.drive = function () {
        this.engine.start();
    };
    return Car;
}());
```

As you can see TS uses a IIFE to wrap the entire class declaration.

It is a nice way to keep everything together.

Another example using decorators:

```
@decorate
class Car {  
    engine: Engine;
    constructor(engine: Engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    drive() { 
        this.engine.start();
    }
}
```

And the output JS:

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    Car.prototype.drive = function () {
        this.engine.start();
    };
    Car = __decorate([
        decorate
    ], Car);
    return Car;
}());
```